# How to get the weights stored from model.predict in keras tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Is there a way I can output the weights from the model.predict() function for the layers of my neural network?

Comment: model.predict() does not have any weights, the model instance is the one that has weights, you can get them with model.get_weights()

Answer (score 0):

```
for l in model.layers:
  for w in l.weights:
    print(w)
```